# Screen glitches or freezes after screen lock with Intel Video Driver

Tags: 13.04, intel-graphics, lightdm, lock-screen

I'm running 13.04, and have an Intel HD 5200 display, using the Intel drivers.

When the screen times-out and locks, most of the time one of two things happens:

- Either the current windows are still visible but frozen
- The screen is black and frozen

In either case the mouse pointer is movable, but I do not get the dialog for typing my password to unlock the screen.

But, if I switch to a VT and back (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>) the login dialog appears immediately.

I've searched all over the net for a few days and cannot find a remedy, though I can occasionally find someone else complaining of basically the same issue, such as here:

[12.04 - Screen glitches / freezes after "Lock Screen"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321667/12-04-screen-glitches-freezes-after-lock-screen)

Though I've a different version of Ubuntu, and a different Intel video chip.

The work-around to (of switching to VT and back) would be livable if it weren't for the fact that the contents of my screen are visible when it is locked up this way!

Any solutions out there?

Comment: removing gnome-screensaver and using xscreensaver instead seems to be a successful work-around (though fairly lame).   If anyone else is wanting to do the same, you can follow instructions here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/292995/configure-screensaver-in-13-04

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and wrote a script that works around it by detecting the screen state and automatically switching virtual terminals (same as a manual Ctrl+Alt+F-key sequence) at the right time. I've only written it for Cinnamon but it should also work for GNOME with minimal config. Try it out and let me know if it works. Maybe we can find a way to patch in a fix for lightdm. You can get it on GitHub and follow the instructions to use it:

https://github.com/appleYaks/switcher